# Firebase getDoc function returning undefined

Tags: react-native, jsx

I have a home screen that pushes an id to a detail screen, the detail screen then gets the information about that document. Whilst the detail screen is requesting the object it is in the loading state. When the object is retrieved the loading state is set to false and the item is loaded.

However, my object is being returned as undefined.

I have checked the following:

1. The id is being passed from the home screen to the detail screen.
2. The object is being retrieved and logged into the console.
3. The object exists in the Firestore database.

I suspect I am setting the load state to false too early as if I reload the app it will work.

### Code:

```
export default function Venue() {
  const { id } = useLocalSearchParams();
  const router = useRouter();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

// MOUNT
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchVenueDetails();
  }, []);

  // FETCH DATA FUNCTIONS
  const fetchVenueDetails = async () => {
    const ref = doc(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, `venue_detail/${id}`);
    try {
      const result = await getDoc(ref);
      console.log(result.data());
      console.log(loading);
      setVenue(result.data());
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false); // SETTING LOADING TO FALSE ONCE DOCUMENT RECEIVED GIVES UNDEFINED
    }
  };
```

### JSX:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {loading ? (
        <View>
          <Text>Loading...</Text>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <>
          <FlatList
            data={offers}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            initialNumToRender={5}
            ListHeaderComponent={renderListHeaderComponent}
            renderItem={renderListItemComponent}
            ListFooterComponent={renderListFooterComponent}
            windowSize={5}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            contentInset={{ bottom: 16 }}
          />
          <VenueBottomBar />
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
```